# Pass string variable into R function

Tags: r, parameter-passing, user-defined-functions

I want to pass a variable name into a function and can't seem to do it. Simply...

```
library (reshape)
test <- function(x) {
 cast(data, x ~ ., length)
}
test(ageg)
```

I get this kickback.

```
Error: Casting formula contains variables not found in molten data: x
```

I know it's simple but I can't find the answer.I want it to simply run

```
cast(data, ageg ~ ., length)
```

Comment: Can you please put the name of the package you used at the begining of your code to make it more reproductible. Thks

Comment: Can't you just pass a formula as argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
test <- function (x) cast(data, as.formula(paste0(x , " ~ .")), length)
```

What you are trying to do is write a formula on the fly. However, a formula is possed on as `quoted` part of the language (IIRC). Therefore, your `x` is not evaluated but looked for in your data as x.

What this does on the other hand is to first create a character string by evaluating x in `paste0`. Then the string is converted to a formula using `as.formula`.